# Integrating $\int(\sin(\log x) + \cos(\log x)) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Integrating 
$$\int(\sin(\log x) + \cos(\log x)) dx$$

I did the sum till here:

[image]

I'm not getting what to do next. I tried LIATE method, but it's not working.

Please help me out

Comment: You'll have to use reduction formulae which are just integration by parts twice _in a specific order so you don't undo your first integration by parts with the second_.

Comment: You can use that $\sin(\log(x))=\frac{x^i-x^{-i}}{2i}$ and $\cos(\log(x))=\frac{x^i+x^{-i}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let 
\begin{equation*}
I = \int {\big(\sin{(\log{x})} + \cos{(\log{x})}\big)\,\mathrm{d}x}.
\end{equation*}
Following your approach,
\begin{equation*}
I = \int {e^{t}(\sin{t} + \cos{t})\, \mathrm{d}t}
\end{equation*}
where $t = \log{x}$.

Now applying the integration by parts formula $\int u \mathrm\,{d}v = uv - \int v\,\mathrm{d}u$ with $u = e^{t}$ and $\mathrm{d}v = (\sin{t} + \cos{t})\,\mathrm{d}t$, we have
\begin{equation*}
I = e^{t}(\sin{t} - \cos{t}) + \int e^{t}(\cos{t} - \sin{t})\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag*{(1)}
\end{equation*}
We can again use integration by parts on the second term of the right-hand side to get
\begin{equation*}
\int e^{t}(\cos{t} - \sin{t})\,\mathrm{d}t= e^{t}(\sin{t} + \cos{t})-\int e^{t}(\sin{t} + \cos{t})\,\mathrm{d}t = e^{t}(\sin{t} + \cos{t}) - I.
\end{equation*}
Notice we have regenerated our starting integral, $I$, which happens frequently when finding indefinite integrals involving both exponential and trigonometric functions. Placing the above equality into $(1)$ gives
\begin{equation*}
2I = 2e^{t}\sin{t} + C
\end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}
I = x\sin{(\log{x})} + C.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity integral of

$$\int e^x( f(x) +f'(x))= f(x)$$

which should give you

$x\sin(\log x) + C$